# VBA Match(True, Range() = 0 , 0)

Tags: excel, vba

I have problem with this code.
The function was intended to display a limited range of cells. Search for the first blank character in the column limiting the size of the range.

```
     Function GetRange(range1 As range)
        Dim number As Long
        number = 
        WorksheetFunction.Match(True, 
        Len(range1.Resize(range1.Rows.Count, 1)) = 0, 0)
        
        GetRange = range1.Resize(number - 1, range1.Column - 1)
        End Function
```

Probably the problem is with this part.(Down) Using a Len in sheet (Match (a, Range ('false, false etc.') = 0) works and returns the result, but doesn't work in Vba

```
Len (range 1.Resize (range.Rows.Count, 1)) = 0
```

Can I replace it somehow?

Comment: Welcome to SO. [It's not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is no good starting point to get help. Read [ask] and [repro] - this will help you to improve your question. As it is for now, we don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please describe in detail what it is supposed to return and if it is to be used only in VBA or also as a `UDF`.

Comment: You cannot write in VBA by taking an Excel formula and replacing each individual word with a VBA word, no more than you could speak French by replacing each individual English word with the corresponding French word from the dictionary. You cannot have line continuations like that either. The process of translating a formula into VBA consists of writing VBA code from scratch such that it has the same observable result as the formula.